# How to import all classes within filesystem in php?

Tags: php, include

The folder structure is like so:

```
/main.php
  /lib/class1.php
  /lib/class2.php
  /lib/class3.php
```

I want to have main.php make available all the classes in lib without doing a ton of require/include. Is this possible? Is it possible to just include all files within a directory?

Comment: Doing so will still perform a ton of `require` :) why not use auto loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an autoloading function to load the class directly from your URL

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include "/lib/".$class_name . '.php'; //Add your folder structure like this
            // ^ Change the path to your specific need
}

//Then Simply
$class1_object = new Class1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes it is entirely possible and quite easy to do. Best way to do so would be to utilize https://www.php.net/autoload

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use an autoload function like @Puciek suggested.

If you are curious about doing it yourself though, you can do something like:

```
$path = "lib/";

foreach(new \DirectoryIterator($path) as $lib){
    if(strstr($lib->getFilename(), ".php")){
        require_once $path.$lib->getFilename();
    }
}
```

The above will use `DirectoryIterator` which is part of the PHP SPL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = '/lib/';

$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach($dir as $spl){
    if($spl->getExtension() != 'php') continue;
    include($spl);
}
```

Basically I looped through the directory's files, filtered out the not php files, then included them. You can feel free to add more filters like files starting with "class" as filenames.

You can also have a look to `glob()` function to php, which returns an array with all the files within a directory:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

---

The good thing about the directory iterator is that you can use a RecursiveDirectoryIterator alongside with a RecursiveIteratorIterator to iterate through a directory tree in a similar way if you want, to get all the files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Autoloading would be a good option for this but that assumes there is a way to map class names to file names, if that is an option you should follow @puciek advise.

Other options would be to create a single include that includes all of the files you want for example in /lib create a file called all.php and define it as

```
include("class1.php");
include("class2.php");
include("class3.php");
```

then in your script you could just include("lib/all.php");

Another option would be to glob the files in a directory then loop through the resultant array and issue an include.

```
$includes = glob("lib/*.php");
foreach($inclues as $inc){
    include($inc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy loading rather than importing everything - http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

```
function autoload($sClass) {
    $sPath = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $sClass) . '.php';
    require_once($sPath);
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');

new My_Class();
```

This is a very stripped back example but it's something to build on. Ideally you would check that the file exists on the include path (http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php), check that the file is readable, that the require/include was successful and that the class exists at the end of the autoload